# What causes SDL2 error 0xc00007b when running my game on other people's computers?

Tags: c++, sdl2, distribution

I made a game using SDL2 and made it available for download.
However, I first tried to install and play it on a different computer, to no avail. I made sure to copy all the .dlls and install all the runtimes, yet I still get error `0xc00007b`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A quick search returns:

```
0xc00007b – the application could not start correctly. This may be because you are mixing up a 32bit environment with a 64bit one
```

Ensure the SDL you have is correct for your program, and that the program targets the correct Windows version (i.e. set Visual Studio to build for x86 if the computer runs 32 bit versions of Windows).